# ITerm2 + Mac Catalina + Zsh + Oh My Zsh + Powerline10K -> not showing fonts properly

Tags: macos-catalina, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, iterm, powerline

I've just upgraded to zsh using the following **tools**:

- ITerm2
- Mac Catalina
- Zsh
- Oh My Zsh
- Powerline10K

This is the **problem** I'm experiencing:
[image]

I am using the following ITerm2 **configuration**:
[image]

BTW I've **already** tried to install the Powerline fonts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've highlighted in the screenshot is *prompt*. Zsh prompt is controlled by *themes*. The theme you are using is apparently Powerlevel10k (your questions says "Powerline10K" but that's almost certainly a mistake).

So you'd like to see powerline glyphs in Powerlevel10k prompt in iTerm2. To do that you need to type `p10k configure`. It'll immediately ask whether you want to installed the recommended font. Say "yes", then restart iTerm2 when prompted, and then again run `p10k configure`. This time it won't offer to install a font and will present you with the choice of prompt styles, some of which use powerline glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have the same font installed as you and it didn't work. Looks like that font only supports powerline in vim in my experience.

Based on the [p10k docs](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#fonts), the [nerd](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#option-3-install-script) font will support all style options. If you still like to use source code pro, you can download nerd version [here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro).

I also fount out that [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) is also a nice font for develop because it is so easy to read. You can use with Nerd Font like this:

[image]